# Iterating over n-dimensional Tensors, Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

There is a three dimensional tensor, which I need to compute the expected values for the elements of the second dimension. I have tried to do it through a for-loop like below, but the error 'tensor is not iterable' has been raised.

```
for i in tf.range(start=0, limit=softed_mul.shape[0]):
    elems = (softed_mul[i, :, :], indexs)
    softed_arg_maxs[i, :, :] = tf.map_fn(lambda x:x[0] * x[1], elems, 
    dtype=tf.float32)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds that there is no way to iterate over a tensor other than using the `tf.map_fn()` function.
Therefore, I tried reshaping the multidimensional tensor, and then I defined another tensor of the same shape similar to the reshaped multi_dimensional tensor. After that by a single call of the `tf.map_fn()` function, all the operations are done.

The primary task that I was trying to do, was computing the expected value (`a[i]*i`) for each entry of different dimensions of the given Tensor.

Take a look to the code.

resahped_softed = tf.reshape(softed_mul, shape= [softed_mul.shape[0]*softed_mul.shape[1]])

```
elems = (resahped_softed, indexs)
softed_arg_maxs_unshaped = tf.map_fn(lambda x: x[0] * x[1], elems, dtype=tf.float32)

softed_arg_maxs = tf.reshape(softed_arg_maxs_unshaped, shape=[softed_mul.shape[0], softed_mul.shape[1], -1])
```